# Mathematica .m file can not open

Tags: mathematica

I add some new .m file to `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/AddOns/Packages/` and then call for it in Mathematica, but failed with the message `Get::noopen: "Cannot open \!\(\"Qdensity.m\"\)."`.

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: I think you could have more luck on [mathematica.se].

Comment: @Braiam This isn't asking how to achieve some particular computational task programmatically in Mathematica. It is, in effect, asking how to load a module. That seems firmly in the intersection of both sites. Just like we help programmers run their compilers and writers run their word processors (even though general programming and writing questions would be closed), there's probably no reason to close this. We only migrate questions that are actually off-topic, or at the explicit request of their authors. A question being on-topic for one site doesn't make it off-topic for all others.